# Using alternative variables in title expression in gganimate's transition_reveal?

Tags: r, gganimate

I'm interested in using alternative variables beyond the time tweening variable for title label information for each frame.

The package Maintainer mentions it usually isn't possible, but offered a small work-around example [here](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/252#issuecomment-450846868). However in his example, it only works if the time variable used conveniently matches up as the index for each element in the data frame.

For most other applications, this isn't realistic. e.g.

```
library(gganimate)
library(tidyverse)

stock <- bind_cols(date = round(as.numeric(time(EuStockMarkets)), 3),
                   EuStockMarkets) ## built-in dataset

stock %>% ggplot(aes(date, FTSE)) +
  geom_line() +
  transition_reveal(date) +
  labs(title = "{stock$FTSE[frame_along]}")
```

[image]

You can see only `NA`s are shown as my time variable can't be coerced into integers. Even if I were to coerce it, it wouldn't show anything as the first element `1991.496` in my time vector is greater than the total of rows in my data frame (1860).

So I thought about doing something like this as a filter:

```
stock %>% ggplot(aes(date, FTSE)) +
  geom_line() +
  transition_reveal(date) +
  labs(title = "{stock$FTSE[which(stock$date == frame_along)]}")
```

What I get is a bunch of flashing frames, but from the frames which are visible I can see the filter does work for getting the correct variable to display in the title. I'm not sure what the issue is here, but I'm keen to get this working.

[image]

**Edit:**

After playing around some more I thought my issue was that I was using `which` to match on a double type vector:

```
stock <- bind_cols(date = as.integer(time(EuStockMarkets)),
                   EuStockMarkets)
stock <- stock %>% group_by(date) %>% summarise(ftse_sum = sum(FTSE))

stock %>% ggplot(aes(date, ftse_sum)) +
  geom_line() +
  transition_reveal(date) +
  labs(title = "{stock$ftse_sum[which(stock$date == frame_along)]}")
```

[image]

Works but this summarised dataset isn't what I'm interested in.

I thought about transforming my time varible to integer (say by multiplying by 1000), and then just converting it back to its proper scale in `scale_x_continuous`.

```
stock <- bind_cols(date = as.integer(round(as.numeric(time(EuStockMarkets)), 3)*1000),
                   EuStockMarkets)

stock %>% ggplot(aes(date, FTSE)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = function(x) x/1000) +
  transition_reveal(date) +
  labs(title = "{stock$FTSE[which(stock$date == as.integer(frame_along))]}")
```

[image]

Goes back to a flashing animation again despite my now filtering specifically on an integer vector and integer values from `frame_along`.

Marco's suggestion:

[image]

Comment: Try using `stock$FTSE[frame]` instead of `stock$FTSE[frame_along]`

Comment: Hi @MarcoSandri, tried your idea. There are no flashing frames anymore but the number shown for the index doesn't seem to align with the line. The final number shown seems to align with the total number of frames in the animation (~ 100) so I'm guessing it's indexing `stock$FTSE` based off of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for.

```
stock %>% ggplot(aes(date, FTSE)) +
  geom_line() +
  transition_reveal(date) +
  labs(title = "{stock$FTSE[which.min(abs(stock$date-frame_along))]}")
```

[image]